# How to run a single Python function using Pypy from a CPython interpreter?

Tags: python, python-decorators, jit, pypy

Is it possible to run a single Python function (or module) using Pypy from a CPython interpreter?

I imagine some use-case similar to a Numba decorator e.g.:

```
@pypy
def elem_sum(*containers):
    for items in zip(*containers):
        yield sum(items)
```

but enjoying the much wider support for Python code that Pypy has compared to Numba.

This is somewhat discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878223/forcing-modules-to-run-in-pypy-from-a-cpython-script-run-pypy-on-part-of-the-co), but some 6 years ago, and at a multiprocessing level, where this may not be generally efficient.
Also the interaction method proposed in the answer, [`execnet`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/execnet), is deprecated. [`Pyro5`](https://pypi.org/project/Pyro5/) seems to be a modern alternative to `execnet` (which would still promote execution at multiprocessing level).